# Azure SQL Server Compatibility Level Differences

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Our Azure SQL master database has a compatibility level of 120 (SQL Server 2014) and our databases are set to 140 (SQL Server 2017).  Do we need to migrate our Azure instance to SQL Server 2017 in order to take full advantage of 2017 query optimizer features?